# Azure Health Check not reading the Health Check from the api

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, health-check

I have setup a health check endpoint on my asp.net core (net 7) web api using the code example below:

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddSqlServer(connectStrings.Main, name: "Main DB")
    .AddApplicationInsightsPublisher();
```

and in the pipline:

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/_health", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = _ => true
        })
        .UseHealthChecks("/_healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = _ => true,
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
        });
```

And in Azure, I have Health Check enabled on the deployed api, with the Path set to /_health.
But the Health Check always results in unhealthy in Azure, but when I navigate to the sites _health endpoint it results in "Healthy". I also tried /_healthz for the json detail result, but that didn't make a difference.

I am at a loss on what else is needed to get Azure to properly read the health of the service.

Comment: is it possible the app is not running during Azure health check test? Maybe you forgot to turn on the 'always on' feature or give a few seconds for it to warm up

Comment: [Health checks for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet) and [health checks for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-8.0) are two different concepts. To put it simply, the App Service monitors the status of the current instance and whether the application is accessible based on metrics. asp.net Core Health is inside the monitoring app.

Comment: It's better to use log middleware to check the details, [here is the sample](https://codeshare.io/eVDERA).

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I checked and it is always on, it is just not reading the health endpoint. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @JasonPan how would I then let Azure App Service Health Check properly balance the service, if it is always resulting in an unhealthy state? From what I have been reading, none of the documentations indicate how to code the endpoint to work with it. All they indicate is a 200 result means healthy, anything else is unhealthy. But in that regard, the /_health endpoint does return a 200 result, and it still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Hi @ChrisCalvert, Again, the health check in app services and asp.net core are not the same concept. If we use php/Java/Nodejs write a application, how app services recognize the health,right?

Comment: Thank you @JasonPan, I do understand what you are indicating, and sorry if I am coming off as no appreciative. I am appreciating the help, but I think there might be something I am not connecting most likely.
I do get what you are saying about health check in asp.net core is different than app services health check, but it still should be returning a 200 OK response anyways, so that is one thing I am confused about.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring Azure App Service instances using Health Check involves choosing a specified path within the web application at regular  [intervals](https://dev.to/evdbogaard/health-checks-in-asp-net-core-web-api-1n44), i.e.,  `https://sampat99.azurewebsites.net/`  is at  `/`  URL path. Health Check enhances application availability by redirecting requests away from unhealthy instances.

[image]

[image]

- The simple code below includes a custom health check.
- Code references are from  [DOC](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/tree/master/src)  and  [DOC2](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/health-checks/samples).

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddControllers();
     services.AddHealthChecks()
     .AddDbContextCheck<DataContext>()
    .AddUrlGroup(new Uri("https://    "), name: " Sampath")
    .AddCheck<CustomHealthCheck>(name: "New Custom Check");


     services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(
             Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
             b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(DataContext).Assembly.FullName)));
    
 }

 
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }

     app.UseHttpsRedirection();

     app.UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
     {
         ResponseWriter = async (context, report) =>
         {
             context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
             var response = new HealthCheckReponse
             {
                 Status = report.Status.ToString(),
                 HealthChecks = report.Entries.Select(x => new IndividualHealthCheckResponse
                 {
                     Components = x.Key,
                     Status = x.Value.Status.ToString(),
                     Description = x.Value.Description

                 }),
                 HealthCheckDuration = report.TotalDuration
             };
             await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
         }
     });
```

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Developer> Developers;
}
```

```
public class IndividualHealthCheckResponse
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Components { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

[image]